jq - is using split() and sub() from current key to append new keys to document the best approach?
I have been working with the systemd journal entries regarding failed auth attempts creating a database of failures. An example of the captured document is:
$ head -n1 comm-auth-nov-15-30.json | jq .
{
  "_BOOT_ID": "87cfcd6210da469f9dbeae43377da8b8",
  "_SYSTEMD_UNIT": "dovecot.service",
  "_SYSTEMD_CGROUP": "/system.slice/dovecot.service",
  "_SOURCE_REALTIME_TIMESTAMP": "1731706246547093",
  "_RUNTIME_SCOPE": "system",
  "_PID": "1214",
  "_CAP_EFFECTIVE": "1fff7fdffff",
  "__SEQNUM": "19453258",
  "_SYSTEMD_SLICE": "system.slice",
  "__CURSOR": "s=8d5dfa285b4f4a3ea5cd05d5ceeb2254;i=128d54a;b=87cfcd6210da469f9dbeae43377da8b8;m=4759afe;t=626fa47ae46c1;x=cff2be34d13c19ab",
  "_MACHINE_ID": "537be4f3e9f842ab9c99453da7e20cae",
  "MESSAGE": "pam_unix(dovecot:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=dovecot ruser=sydney@mydomain.com rhost=68.197.134.164",
  "_EXE": "/usr/lib/dovecot/auth",
  "__SEQNUM_ID": "8d5dfa285b4f4a3ea5cd05d5ceeb2254",
  "SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER": "auth",
  "__REALTIME_TIMESTAMP": "1731706246547137",
  "__MONOTONIC_TIMESTAMP": "74816254",
  "SYSLOG_FACILITY": "10",
  "SYSLOG_RAW": "<85>Nov 15 15:30:46 auth: pam_unix(dovecot:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=dovecot ruser=sydney@mydomain.com rhost=68.197.134.164 ",
  "_UID": "0",
  "_GID": "0",
  "_HOSTNAME": "valkyrie",
  "_SYSTEMD_INVOCATION_ID": "256f2b33f89f4bdd910ec8ffe40e5825",
  "SYSLOG_TIMESTAMP": "Nov 15 15:30:46 ",
  "_COMM": "auth",
  "_TRANSPORT": "syslog",
  "PRIORITY": "5",
  "_CMDLINE": "dovecot/auth -w"
}

To make the document more useful, I needed to use jq to append ruser and rhost keys with the information from the MESSAGE key isolating the ruser and rhost information so it is easily searchable, and can be queried by those keys. in the database. The information I wanted from the MESSAGE key that  I split() and then used sub() on was:
  " ... ruser=sydney@mydomain.com rhost=68.197.134.164",

To accomplish this, I used split(" ") to split MESSAGE into an array, cheated and used the fixed indexes 7 and 8 to pipe the strings containing "ruser=..." and "rhost=..." to sub("^.+=";"") to remove the prefixes. To my happy surprise, it worked just fine:
$ head -n1 comm-auth-nov-15-30.json | jq '. += {"ruser":(.MESSAGE | split (" "))[7] | sub ("^.+=";""),"rhost":(.MESSAGE | split (" "))[8] | sub ("^.+=";"")}'

With the results I was looking for:
{
  "_BOOT_ID": "87cfcd6210da469f9dbeae43377da8b8",
  "_SYSTEMD_UNIT": "dovecot.service",
  "_SYSTEMD_CGROUP": "/system.slice/dovecot.service",
  "_SOURCE_REALTIME_TIMESTAMP": "1731706246547093",
  "_RUNTIME_SCOPE": "system",
  "_PID": "1214",
  "_CAP_EFFECTIVE": "1fff7fdffff",
  "__SEQNUM": "19453258",
  "_SYSTEMD_SLICE": "system.slice",
  "__CURSOR": "s=8d5dfa285b4f4a3ea5cd05d5ceeb2254;i=128d54a;b=87cfcd6210da469f9dbeae43377da8b8;m=4759afe;t=626fa47ae46c1;x=cff2be34d13c19ab",
  "_MACHINE_ID": "537be4f3e9f842ab9c99453da7e20cae",
  "MESSAGE": "pam_unix(dovecot:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=dovecot ruser=sydney@mydomain.com rhost=68.197.134.164",
  "_EXE": "/usr/lib/dovecot/auth",
  "__SEQNUM_ID": "8d5dfa285b4f4a3ea5cd05d5ceeb2254",
  "SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER": "auth",
  "__REALTIME_TIMESTAMP": "1731706246547137",
  "__MONOTONIC_TIMESTAMP": "74816254",
  "SYSLOG_FACILITY": "10",
  "SYSLOG_RAW": "<85>Nov 15 15:30:46 auth: pam_unix(dovecot:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=dovecot ruser=sydney@mydomain.com rhost=68.197.134.164 ",
  "_UID": "0",
  "_GID": "0",
  "_HOSTNAME": "valkyrie",
  "_SYSTEMD_INVOCATION_ID": "256f2b33f89f4bdd910ec8ffe40e5825",
  "SYSLOG_TIMESTAMP": "Nov 15 15:30:46 ",
  "_COMM": "auth",
  "_TRANSPORT": "syslog",
  "PRIORITY": "5",
  "_CMDLINE": "dovecot/auth -w",
  "ruser": "sydney@mydomain.com",
  "rhost": "68.197.134.164"
}

I only had 4300 records, so it wasn't that slow, but as I work to learn jq I worry that this was a naive approach that would be better done another way. Is this a reasonable approach to split() and rely on the fixed positions for indexes 7 & 8 to grab the strings and pipe to sub() for the result? Or, is there a better way to approach this?

"Is this a reasonable approach to split() and rely on the fixed positions for indexes 7 & 8 to grab the strings" -- can you guarantee the input will never change? If so, it's reasonable, if not, you'd need to describe the possible ways the input could change in order to answer this. As far as performance, is this an application bottleneck? I wouldn't worry about optimizing or DRYing out a quick utility that's parsing a tiny structure like this.

Well, that is a good point, and no, you can never guarantee much of anything when freedesktop.org is involved in the loop, but until an upstream code-change occurs, the systemd journal MESSAGE fields are fixed at present. My concern here is whether I overlooked an obviously easier/better way to accomplish grabbing the ruser and rhost information needed to append creating the new keys. The only option I could think of to make this more generic would be to so a search within the split() results to return the indexes needed, but that seemed excessive?

Kudos on an impressive one-line hack.
Of course the usual trouble with "long" one-liners is maintainability.
Breaking this out as a small jq script would give you a bit more
space to reveal parallel structure and to be more paranoid about matching.
Given the small number of fields per record, I wouldn't worry
about performance gotchas.
pipeline
Here is another way to come at it, filtering the input before jq ever sees it.
  { line = $0 }
$8 ~ /tty=dovecot/ &&
/^  "MESSAGE": "pam_unix.dovecot:auth.: authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=dovecot ruser=/  {
    sub("ruser=", "", $9)
    sub("rhost=", "", $10)
    print "  \"ruser\": \""  $9 "\","
    print "  \"rhost\": \"" $10
  }
  { print line }

output:
  ...
  "ruser": "sydney@mydomain.com",
  "rhost": "68.197.134.164",
  "MESSAGE": "pam_unix(dovecot:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=dovecot ruser=sydney@mydomain.com rhost=68.197.134.164",
  ...

The match on $8 is intended to spare a maintenance engineer
from having to count how many fields before ruser & rhost.
The long match reflects paranoia about the message format
possibly changing, plus it has documentation value.
There are other scripting languages supporting regex,
which might be more convenient than the macOS awk this is written in.
If your only porting target is linux then gawk's gensub() matching
can be a little shorter.
trailing comma
This is more fragile than the OP code in that it silently ignores future
"changed" messages, and assumes that at least one more field will appear.
So in a python-based pipeline stage I might import json for safety.

Well, damn, that makes sense, and it really works with the prettified json output. The raw output from journalctl is all one line, which is what prompted the one-liner. Still, the number of records are small so I can simply pipe to jq . first to get the prettified form and then apply the script. Thank you!

For the single-line json format, I resorted to awk 'BEGIN { RS = ","; ORS = "," } /^"MESSAGE":/ {line = $0; sub("ruser=", "", line); sub("rhost=", "", line); if ((n = split (line, arr, / /)) > 1) { $0 = "\042ruser\042:\042" arr[n-1] "\042,\042rhost\042:\042" arr[n] "," line; }} { print }' which I had to pipe to sed /^,$/d to remove the final ',' to avoid the jq: parse error: Expected value before ',' due to file ORS output.... Mixed on whether trying to use shell tools on single-line json is preferable to the validation provided by jq?

Well, like I said, JSON fragility is a worry. What I admire about the OP one-liner is that it copes with "trailing comma" more robustly than any grep / awk / sed approach would. If you desire that, then jq or perhaps a python import json is the way to go.

In addition to J_H's answer, I arrived at a jq solution I'm happy with and will go ahead an pass it along for anyone else it may help. One of the things I disliked about the original was having to count indexes using 7 & 8. I haven't completely solved that problem in a purely generic way, but have made progress by being able to select the last two elements of the array created from MESSAGES with split().
Progress was also made defining a function in jq to process and split the MESSAGE key making the routine a bit easier to read. Originally we had the equivalent of:
## extracts ruser=... and rhost=... from  MESSAGE key and appends new keys
#  ruser and rhost to object
#

. += {
  "ruser":(.MESSAGE | split (" "))[7] | sub ("^.+=";""),
  "rhost":(.MESSAGE | split (" "))[8] | sub ("^.+=";"")
}

To eliminate the hardcoded indexes, we were able to get the number of elements in the resulting array using length and then by defining a function msg that handles .MESSAGE | split (" "), the solution ended up relatively short and readable:
def msg: .MESSAGE | split (" ");
. += {
  "ruser":msg[msg | length - 2] | sub ("^.+=";""),
  "rhost":msg[msg | length - 1] | sub ("^.+=";"")
}

The length - 1 accounts for the zero based array indexing. I'm sure there are further improvements that can be made, but this is acceptably fast and preserves json validation provided by jq.
The long-form equivalent without defining a function looks like:
. += {
  "ruser":(.MESSAGE | split (" "))[(.MESSAGE | split (" ")) | length - 2] | sub ("^.+=";""),
  "rhost":(.MESSAGE | split (" "))[(.MESSAGE | split (" ")) | length - 1] | sub ("^.+=";"")
}

Example use to process the journalctl -o json ... output with the script above saved as add_ruser_rhost.jq adding the ruser and rhost keys at the end of the object:
jq -f add_ruser_rhost.jq journal.json > comm-auth-nov-15-30+ruser-rhost.json

